# Override save method in Django not working

Tags: python, django

My goal with the following code is to create an athlete object and override the save method to automatically set the `category` for a given athlete based on the `born_date`.

The `Category` class will be inherited in other models too. The list within the class serves as validation purposes for the save method and the tuples for choice fields (used in other models).

Although everything seems right, I ran some test in the shell and the code is saving whatever `born_date` is inputed. Why is that the case? Can someone shed some light on the problem? Thanks

```
  from django.db import models
  from datetime import datetime

  class Category:
       
       list_categories = [
           'u12',
           'u13',
           'u14',
           'u15',
           'u16',
           'u17',
           'u18',
           'u19',
           'u20',
           'u21',
           ]
   
       CATEGORIES = [
           ('U12', 'u12'),
           ('U13', 'u13'),
           ('U14', 'u14'),
           ('U15', 'u15'),
           ('U17', 'u17'),
           ('U19', 'u19'),
           ('U21', 'u21'),
       ]
   

   class Athlete(models.Model, Category):
   
       name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
       born_date = models.DateField()
       category = models.CharField(max_length=3)
   
       def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
           year_now = datetime.date.today().year
           year_born_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(self.born_date, "%Y-%m-%d")
           self.category = 'u{}'.format(year_now - year_born_obj.year)
           if self.category in Category.list_categories:
               try: 
                   super(Athlete, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
               except ValueError:
                   print('Category does not exist. Check born date')
                   
                   
       def __str__(self):
           return self.name
```

Here is the shell output:

```
>>> a1 = Athlete.objects.create(name='Foo', born_date='1990-02-05')
>>> a1.save()
>>> a1.category
'u30'
>>> a1.category in Category.list_categories
False
```

Comment: I think you need to add more categories, your born year is filled as `1990`. So the logic math is `2020-1990 = 30`

Comment: The categories are listed (list_categories) in a specified range, within 'u12' to 'u21', hence, u30 exceeds that list and should not be saved.

Comment: Baivaras's answer below will probably work.  One other thing you are missing is the database validation which would at least prevent this, even if your logic is wrong.  You need to set the "choices" attribute for category, so that it uses your options.  (choices=CATEGORIES)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not assign category value to the object if you do not want to save it, I made some changes to your code.

Try to do like this:

```
category = 'u{}'.format(year_now - year_born_obj.year)
if category in Category.list_categories:
    self.category = category
else:
    print('Category does not exist. Check born date')
super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Please ask if you do not understand anything or it's not working:)

Comment: It did work! Thanks. But should i not use try/except, and, set Athlete and self as atributes in super()? Why? Thanks again!

Comment: although your solution have worked the data is still being saved to the database.

Comment: i just moved super().save() into the if statement and now the data is not been saved when it shouldn't.

Comment: In your code, you try to save the Athlete object, which will always happen and it will not go to the exception. If you want to use try/except then you need to raise that exception if category is not on the list. In that case, you will not save the Athlete object if the category does not match. https://pastebin.com/u2yJ9r2a

Comment: To answer you super() question simply it's Python 2 and Python 3 change, please read https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/ it's quite explanatory

Answer (score 1):

You can upgrade your source code based on the following way. I made some modifications to your code. Hope that will help you a lot.

```
from django.db import models
from datetime import datetime

class Athlete(models.Model):
    categories = [
        ("U12", "u12"),
        ("U13", "u13"),
        ("U14", "u14"),
        ("U15", "u15"),
        ("U16", "u16"),
        ("U17", "u17"),
        ("U18", "u18"),
        ("U19", "u19"),
        ("U20", "u20"),
        ("U21", "u21"),
    ]

    name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    born_date = models.DateField(default=None, null=True)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=3, default=None, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            age = "u{age}".format(age=datetime.today().year - datetime.strptime(self.born_date, "%Y-%m-%d").year)
            category = "".join(ct[0] for ct in self.categories if age == ct[1])
            self.category = category if category != "" else None
        except Exception as exp:
            print("Exception: {exp}".format(exp=exp))
        return super(Athlete, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: @Sayem_Bari Straight forward indeed. Thanks a lot! I had to rename `category` to `category_athlete` to avoid clashing when inheriting Athlete in other models, to use its attributes. That said, when I try to create new Athlete objects i get the following error: `NOT NULL constraint failed: <app_name>_athlete.category_athlete`. Why is that happening? Tks

Comment: @Sayem_Bari I believe i have found the problem in your code. If the category doesn't exists the value None is passed to it, so, it it passes through the exception and output an error in the database. If the category exists the data is saved as expected.

Comment: @Igor, Welcome anyway!!! Please try to make sure if you have done the same thing as I coded. I set the `null` properties `True` for `category` field, so that if it doesn't match with any of the listed categories, it can set `None` value by default.